# covering spaces of rectangles having all sides idntified

Tags: algebraic-topology

How to find all the covering spaces of a rectangle having all the sides identified (upto isomorphism)?

Here is how I have approached: Let's call the given space $X$. It is easy to calculate $\pi_1(X)=\mathbb Z / 4\mathbb Z$. If $Y$ is any covering  space of $X$, then $p_*(\pi_1(Y))$ is a subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$. There are only 3 subgroups of $\mathbb Z / 4\mathbb Z$. I don't know how to approach beyond this point.